Can't start/connect postgresql
I don't understand but when I noticed postgresql seemed to not working like usual, and I've been dealing with this issue, but can't see the problem. Thank you for your help.
journalctl:
$ sudo journalctl -xe
8月 25 13:24:06 pcname sudo[3926683]:     username : TTY=pts/171 ; PWD=/media/username/external/pg/umami_240824/master/umami-master ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service postgresql restart
 8月 25 13:24:06 pcname sudo[3926683]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
 8月 25 13:24:06 pcname systemd[1]: postgresql.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- The unit postgresql.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
 8月 25 13:24:06 pcname systemd[1]: Stopped PostgreSQL RDBMS.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit postgresql.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- A stop job for unit postgresql.service has finished.
-- 
-- The job identifier is 253013 and the job result is done.
 8月 25 13:24:06 pcname systemd[1]: Stopping PostgreSQL RDBMS...
-- Subject: A stop job for unit postgresql.service has begun execution

status:
$ sudo systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2024-08-25 13:24:06 JST; 3min 43s ago
    Process: 3926691 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 3926691 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 8月 25 13:24:06 pcname systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
 8月 25 13:24:06 pcname systemd[1]: Finished PostgreSQL RDBMS.

restart:
$ sudo systemctl start postgresql.service
$ 

psql commands doesn't work:
$ psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
$ 
$ sudo -i -u postgres psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

postgresql log doesn't show anything:
$ cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
$ wc /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
0 0 0 /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log

server:
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

Edit
Here's the one previous log I was missing to see. As you can see I see background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1555) exited with exit code 1 line (I don't understand this but sounds like the culprit).
$ cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log.1
2024-08-21 06:10:58.297 JST [1266] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2024-08-21 06:10:58.298 JST [1266] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2024-08-21 06:10:58.299 JST [3135353] postgres@postgres FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2024-08-21 06:10:58.303 JST [1266] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1555) exited with exit code 1
2024-08-21 06:10:58.304 JST [1550] LOG:  shutting down
2024-08-21 06:10:58.315 JST [1266] LOG:  database system is shut down

